# Do people still name their homepage "index.html" these days?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create my own website and if you read the rules, they say you should name your homepage or mainpage index.html.  Is that really still needed today or is there a reason why we should do that other than convention?  It it something scrapers/crawlers look for?

As my website doesn't really have a page that I consider the "home" page or "main" page, it makes no sense for me to call one index.html.  I'd prefer to just call them by what content the page displays.

Thanks!

Comment: It's just the default page for example Apache looks for when someone accesses a URL that does not have a specific file name given. This is configurable, but nonetheless index.html and index.htm are the standard names a webserver looks for.

Comment: If your website doesn't have a "home" or "main" page, where will people start looking at your content?  The landing page is defined by you, so you decide if that's index or something else.  But, as already answered, the index file is defaulted by most server software.

Comment: ok that's helpful.  i'll just name one index then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many servers use `index.` as  the page to show a visitor when they see the root of your site. You can change that in server configuration if you want. But, out of the box, everyone uses index because that's what servers are configured for.

Comment: ok, thanks that helps a lot. If it's such a convention that it's used by ohter stuff, then i'll arbitrarily name a page the "index" page even tho depending on if you rae logged in or not,, the page you first see can be different

Comment: Sure, in large frameworks such as CodeIgniter and Laravel, for example, index.php does nothing but initiate the application. The rest of the code decides what to show.